# Pyspark job stuck at writing a job to s3 bucket

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running pyspark on EMR, and my cluster is getting stuck at below screen shot while writing data into S3 bucket. I am able to see a temp folder in the bucket, and is taking 30 min without any output.

Emr screenshot.

[image]

I have also set this parameter which is not useful

```
spark_context.Hadoop configuration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
enter code here
```

It was working previously, after adding these UDF's it is slowing down :

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def clean_phone(phone): 
    try:
        if phone is not None:  
            phone_cleaned= ''.join(e for e in phone if (e.isnumeric() or e=='+' or 'EXT' in phone.upper() ))
            if len(phone_cleaned)==11 and phone_cleaned.replace('+','').isdigit():
                phone_number=str(phonenumbers.parse(phone_cleaned.replace("+",''),"US")).split(" ")
                if phone_number[5]==10 :
                  phone_number[2]+"-"+phone_number[5]
                else:  
                  return ""  
            elif len(phone_cleaned)<10 : 
                        return ""
            else:  
                            phone_number=str(phonenumbers.parse(phone_cleaned,"US")).split(" ") 
                            if len(phone_number[5])==10 :
                                return phone_number[2]+"-"+phone_number[5]+('-'+phone_number[7] if 'EXT' in phone_cleaned.upper() else "")
                            else:
                                return ""
        else:
            return "" 
    except Exception as x:
         print("Error Occured in phone udf, Error: " + str(x))        



@udf(returnType=StringType())
def clean_email(email): 
    try:
        regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b' 
        if email is not None:
            if '%20' in email:
                email=email.replace("%20","")
            if '.jpg' in email:
                email=""     
            email_corrected= ''.join(e for e in email if (e.isalnum() or e in ['.', '@','-','_']))        
            if(re.fullmatch(regex, email_corrected)):
                return email_corrected
            else:
                    return ""   
        else:
            return ""
    except Exception as x:
         print("Error Occured in email udf, Error: " + str(x))               


         
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def clean_zip(zip): 
    try:
        
        regex = r'[A-Za-z]'    
        if zip is not None and len(re.findall('\d\d\d',zip))>0:
            zip_corrected=''.join(e for e in zip if (e.isnumeric() or e=='-') )
            if "-" in zip_corrected:
                """Check cases when we have "-" in zip code <5"""
                if (zip_corrected.split("-")[0]).isdigit():
                    zip_corrected=zip_corrected.split("-")[0]
                elif (zip.split("-")[1]).isdigit():
                    zip_corrected=zip_corrected.split("-")[1]  
            elif zip_corrected.isdigit() and len(zip_corrected)<5 :   
                """Check cases when ;enth of zip code <5"""
                zip_corrected= zip_corrected.zfill(5)       
        else :
            return ""  
        if len(**zipcodes.matching(zip_corrected)**)>0:
            return   zip_corrected  
        else:
            return ""   

        # if len(zip_corrected)==5 and zip_corrected.isdigit()==True :
        #         return zip_corrected
        # elif len(zip_corrected)>5 :
        #         return ""
        # elif zip_corrected.isdigit() and len(zip_corrected)<5   :
        #     return zip_corrected.zfill(5)  
        # else:
        #     return ""
    except Exception as x:  
        print("Error Occured in zip udf, Error: " + str(x))
```

Comment: Are you using `udfs`?

Comment: yes, 3 UDF's . Before UDF's it was working as expected

Comment: @the_ordinary_guy: any help is appreciated..

Comment: Could you post your code and what's your data size?

Comment: did the data size increase now? if yes, the udfs might have difficult time in coping up with it. Try to run the experiment with lesser data and see if that succeeds. Then we can see what to do later...

Comment: @the_ordinary_guy: Thedata size didn't increase; it is the same size. After adding UDF it is getting struct at inserting data to S3

Comment: So can you try with less data and see if it succeeds?

Comment: sure will give it a try and get back to you, Thanks

Comment: @the_ordinary_guy : So I have reduced the file size  from 1 GB to 300MB  csv file, it is working fine, I think the main issue is with these three UDF. I have posted the code.Can you, please have a look

Comment: @JonathanLam : Added UDF's code, please have a look

Comment: you have two functions doing regex operations. The second udf looks massive comparison. Can you remove the second udf and try with the 1GB data?

Comment: I had observed that issue is with zipcode parser (in precise zipcodes.matching -- here it is taking more time). Can you please suggest how to re write this

Comment: instead of udf using regex, can you try `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract`. Have a look here https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html

Comment: @the_ordinary_guy the statement zipcodes.matching is where it is failing, if I remove it I am able to run my program. Dont knowhow to bypass this

Comment: try the regex operations with `pyspark.sql.functions` library. They are optmised to be used in spark,